# parallel lambda executions on dynamodb update

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm building an aws lambda service which processes entries to a dynamodb table. The process is quite time consuming, around 2 seconds per entry and the entries are added in batches of around 20 at the time. I'm looking for a way to process all the entries in a batch simultaneously, as in triggering a separate lambda event for each added entry so that they can all run in parallel and thus be completed quicker. As far as I've understood, a dynamodb trigger polls a few times a second and sends all the updated entries to a single lambda event. Is there a way to configure the trigger to create concurrent events for each entry?
I'm new to aws so please excuse me if I'm using the wrong nomenclature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you are using [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) to have your lambda triggered?

There are a lot of nuances which determine how many Lambda Functions are executed in parallel to process your DynamoDB Streams. You should test your implementation to see if you're building up an ever longer back log of items which need to be processed, or if the latency to process those items is too long for your requirements.

If this were the case, you could introduce [Amazon SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) into your solution. In the Lambda Function, consuming your DynamoDB Stream, you'd only forward the item into a SQS queue. This queue can afterwards easily be processed in parallel by many Lambda Functions.

---

**Update based on your comment**

1 minute of delay might not be too long, you need to know which delays are acceptable for your business use case. If you think 1 minute of delay is too long,  than you can combine the following serverless patterns to process the items in parallel:

- [DynamoDB to Lambda](https://serverlessland.com/patterns/dynamodb-lambda)
   (you are already doing this)
- [Lambda to SQS](https://serverlessland.com/patterns/lambda-sqs)
- [SQS to Lambda](https://serverlessland.com/patterns/sqs-lambda)

Alternatively, you can also you can also trigger [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) directly from your Lambda Function which is subscribed the DynamoDB Stream. AWS Step Functions is a workflow service, which also allows you to orchestrate a parallel execution. The pattern for this would be [Lambda to Step Functions](https://serverlessland.com/patterns/lambda-sfn).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I'm using the DynamoDB Streams as you mentioned. The DynamoDB table in question won't have a lot of traffic as it is for an early pilot so I don't think there will be a backlog. The issue is that once the table is updated (with a batch of around 20 items), the process will take around a minute to finish, if processed in series by the same lambda execution. If i instead can start 20 lambda executions in parallel, that data could be processed in just a few seconds. Are you suggesting a lambda which sends each item to a separate sqs and add that sqs q to a lambda?

Comment: @JohanKuylenstierna I extended the answer